# Issue with site.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database

I'm trying to make my own CS:GO gambling site. I already did it on localhost using VPS. This time i got a domain and almost everything is fine. The thing is when I want to run site.js this error comes up:

```
[erzis@s1]:</usr/home/erzis/bot>$ node site.js
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.731] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.734] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8000]
code: 'EPERM',
errno: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '0.0.0.0' 
port: 8000 }
Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8000
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
at listen (net.js:1286:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
at Server.listen.Server.attach (/usr/home/erzis/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
at new Server (/usr/home/erzis/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:52:17)
at Server (/usr/home/erzis/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:40:41)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/home/erzis/bot/site.js:3:30)
at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.758] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 15865731
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.759] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 15865732
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.759] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 15865733
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.761] [TRACE] [default] - Roll 4130
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.761] [INFO] [default] - DB Connection ID: 15865734
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.762] [TRACE] [default] - Sucesfully updated history
[2017-01-05 13:04:26.762] [WARN] [default] - Loaded hashd8b710dfa2c8a3d990ca1dc7cc0a91754ac20aa6139fb7f6d44b58ee31ece8dc
[2017-01-05 13:04:27.789] [TRACE] [default] - New prices loaded
[2017-01-05 13:04:29.728] [TRACE] [default] - Strange error
[2017-01-05 13:04:29.729] [DEBUG] [default] - { [Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8080]
code: 'EPERM',
errno: 'EPERM',
syscall: 'listen',
address: '0.0.0.0',
port: 8080 }
Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8080
at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:873:11)
at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:896:20)
at Server._listen2 (net.js:1237:19)
at listen (net.js:1286:10)
at Server.listen (net.js:1382:5)
at Server.listen.Server.attach (/usr/home/erzis/node_modules/socket.io/lib/index.js:228:9)
at null._onTimeout (/usr/home/erzis/bot/site.js:618:29)
at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:92:15)
```

I looked over internet and the only answer I found is that the port is locked. So I changed it to 80, but it still wasn't working.

I think it might be something with this domain and ports, but I'm not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have permission to listen on 0.0.0.0:8080. Check if you have to listen on a specific interface or if anything is progibiting you from listening on port 8080.

`Error: listen EPERM 0.0.0.0:8080`

Try to listen on port 8080 using netcat (if you got shell access): `nc -l 8080` to check if this is a problem with your own permissions or with the application itself.

Comment: Hmm, I think I have to. When I was doing it on my private VPS everything worked, because I was root, but here I'm using a hosting which I guess doesn't provide me full access...